# Rails: following rolify tutorial but encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'rolify', '~> 5.1'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.15'
rails 5.0
ruby 2.3.0

I am following rolify tutorial to learn rolify. https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial

I did every step exactly as tutorial indicated. After installation and configuration, when I moved to the usage and run `user = User.new` in console, it showed me thousands lines of errors like this. Anybody could tell me how to fix this?

```
 1681 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/extend-command.rb
 1682 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/output-method.rb
 1683 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/notifier.rb
 1684 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/slex.rb
 1685 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-token.rb
 1686 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb
 1687 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/src_encoding.rb
 1688 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/magic-file.rb
 1689 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/input-method.rb
 1690 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/locale.rb
 1691 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb.rb
 1692 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb
 1693 /Users/Cy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb
 1694 /Users/Cy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb
 1695 /Users/Cy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/console/app.rb
 1696 /Users/Cy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/console/helpers.rb
 1697 /Users/Cy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/y.rb
 1698 /Users/Cy/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it might be a bug triggered by Spring Gem.

So my solution is input `spring stop` before `rails c`

or just remove `gem spring` in Gemfile if you do not need it.

Try it!

Here you can find more about it:

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/195

https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/493